# Database does not store data. I get the "SQLiteLog: (1) near "Name": syntax error" from Android Studio log

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I get from "SQLiteLog: (1) near "Name": syntax error" after the addPatient() method is called and the data given by addPatient() method is not stored in the database.
At first, I suspect that something might be wrong with my "CREATE TABLE" query but I have tried everything and I couldn't figure out what was wrong.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        //===============Create a table for Patient
        String query = "CREATE TABLE TABLE_PATIENT (COLUMN_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                "COLUMN_USERNAME TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_PASSWORD TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_FIRSTNAME TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_LASTNAME TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_AGE TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_GENDER TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_PHONE TEXT, " +
                "COLUMN_ADDRESS TEXT);";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }//End of onCreate()


    //Add a new Patient Row to the database
    public void addPatient(Patient patient)
    {
Log.i(TAG, "addPatient("+patient.getUserName()+")");
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_ID, patient.getU_Id());
        values.put(COLUMN_USERNAME, patient.getUserName());
        values.put(COLUMN_PASSWORD, patient.getPassword());
        values.put(COLUMN_FIRSTNAME, patient.getFirstName());
        values.put(COLUMN_LASTNAME,patient.getLastName());
        values.put(COLUMN_AGE, patient.getAge());
        values.put(COLUMN_GENDER,patient.getGender());
        values.put(COLUMN_PHONE,patient.getPhoneNumber());
        values.put(COLUMN_ADDRESS, patient.getAddress());

        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
try
{
    db.insert(TABLE_PATIENT, null, values);
    db.close();
}catch (Exception e)
{
    Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
}

    }//End of addPatient()
```

Comment: Unless your `COLUMN_...` constants have exactly the same value as their name, your column names in the `CREATE` and the `INSERT` are different.

Comment: It's easier if you don't have spaces in those column name constant values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you have defined these variables:

```
String COLUMN_ID = "id";
String COLUMN_USERNAME = "username";
....................................
```

or something like that.
If you have spaces in the names of the columns you must use square brackets or backticks around them, like:

```
String COLUMN_USERNAME = "[user name]";
```

In your `CREATE TABLE` statement you define the column names as:

```
"COLUMN_ID", "COLUMN_USERNAME", ....
```

because you use the variable names and not their values. 
But in `addPatient()` method you are putting values to the `ContentValues` object by using their actual names. 
To solve your problem, 1st uninstall the app from the device you are testing it, so the database is deleted.
 
Then change the `CREATE TABLE` statement like this:

```
String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PATIENT +" (" + 
        COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
        COLUMN_USERNAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_FIRSTNAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_LASTNAME + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_AGE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_GENDER + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_PHONE + " TEXT, " +
        COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT)";
```

and rerun to recreate the database with the correct column names.